# Google Firebase - Dynamically update text area using firebase data

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a simple text area on a webpage. When the webpage is loaded, the text area is populated with data from my firebase database. 
It looks like this:

[image]

However, when I update my firebase database and add new data, this happens:

[image]

Rather than adding the new data to the text area, the entire dataset gets added to the text area. Can any body help me so that the text area just updates and adds any missing data?

Here is the code:

```js
var ref = new Firebase(*LINK TO FIREBASE*);

        ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {

        console.log(snapshot.val());

        var data = snapshot.val();

        for (var key in data) {

          if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

            document.getElementById('textAreaFirebase').value += data[key] + " ";

            console.log('Value Added');

          };
        }
      });
```

```html
<div id="textBoxFirebase">
    <form>
    Firebase Data<br>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textAreaFirebase"></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's quite an interesting bug but it's how you handle the new data.

In the `ref.on('value', () => { // do something })` it gets the whole new value again.

So if the database has 50, 32

then you add 73

`snapshot.val() => 50, 32, 73`

And in the loop you are doing `+=` to the existing text already present.

So you end up with `50, 32` + `50, 32, 73`

I'd suggest you try this...

### Code

```
var ref = new Firebase(*LINK TO FIREBASE*);

        ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {

        console.log(snapshot.val());

        var data = snapshot.val();

        // Added new =============================

        const textArea = document.getElementById('textAreaFirebase')

        textArea.value = ""

        // Reset of value complete ===============

        for (var key in data) {

          if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

            textArea.value += data[key] + " ";

            console.log('Value Added');

          };
        }
      });
```